# error in csync2 two server data using csync2 tools

Tags: synchronization

i m trying csync2 two server data. but when  i m using tail -f /var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log ,there is an error showing                           ---Received line too long for buffer size (100), giving up.
Failure on startup

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as described. Initially I was using the version found in debians main repository (1.34-2.2), but encountered some errors regarding file sizes. I switched to Version 2.0-rc1 and compiled it myself. While the size related errors where gone I ended up with "Received line too long for buffer size (100), giving up".

I switched from inetd to xinetd after I noticed that my setup worked when invoking the csync2 server via cli with "csync2 -iii". I used the setup which I found in the official malinglist (http://lists.linbit.com/pipermail/csync2/2015-January/001103.html) where a user had the same problem.

While looking at the source files of csync2 again I noticed a file named "csync2.xinetd", which includes also a sample configuration for xinetd (http://git.linbit.com/gitweb.cgi?p=csync2.git;a=blob_plain;f=csync2.xinetd;hb=HEAD).
To my suprise there was another switch in the config (-l) which had no reference in the documentation (as far as I can see). Setting up xinetd with "-i -l" as server_args instead of "-i" only as described in the official doc did the trick.

Hope it helps

zak